# ng-multiselect-dropdown - TypeError: Cannot read property 'idField' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, angular9

Followed steps as per 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown for angular 9

received below error in browser console

TypeError: Cannot read property 'idField' of undefined

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved but moving `[settings]` param prior to `[data]` para.

Example:

```
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
        [settings]="dropdownSettings"
        [data]="dropdownList"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    >
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: @Tomislav:its worked for me but can you tell m why its working after moving setting to [data]?

Comment: @Kapilsoni From documentation: `data - Array of items from which to select. Should be an array of objects with id and text properties. You can also use custom properties. In that case you need to map idField and textField properties. As convenience, you may also pass an array of strings, in which case the same string is used for both the ID and the text(no mapping is required)`

Comment: it is strange but it solved the issue. what could be the reason behind this issue ?

Comment: This indeed works. The reason behind it??

Comment: Working hahahaha!

Comment: Omg worked for me too. I don't understand it!

Answer (score 4):

Please set

```
dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings = {
..Other settings,
idField: 'id',
textField: 'text'};
```

set your dropdown list as

```
dropdownList= [{id: '1', text: 'Sample Text'}, ..]
```

Also set [settings] before [data] in html as indicated by Abraham Cm

Comment: Adding settings before data worked of me.

Answer (score 2):

yes, solution above (with [settings] binding before [data]) works because ng-multiselect-dropdown has setters in **data** and **settings** inputs. **data** setter is using **settings** input. So in this case order is important. It also suprised me at the beginning. Look at source code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved issue by above two steps but I needed to restart the application then only application ran successfully.

1. Sequence is important i.e. **[settings] before [data]**
2. settings must be initialized properly in the component
3. Restart the application by closing and opening vs code project. This was even needed when there was issue in importing module.